# Structure the code with async and await operations

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I want to structure my code in a good way using the Await and Async operations in my code. Here is what I want to do:

```
public myMainFunction()
{
    var stream = App.GetResourceStream(new Uri("Assets/Tiles/gradiant-mask.png", UriKind.Relative));
    byte[] byteStream = new byte[stream.Stream.Length];

    stream.Stream.Read(byteStream, 0, byteStream.Length);

    Task tsk = getBlurredbitmap1(session, blurBuffer);
    tsk.ContinueWith((myTask) =>
    {
        FACTORY.imageFusion(blurBuffer, byteStream.AsBuffer()):                       
    });
}
```

In the main function I cannot use await operation because I am overriding this function so signature has to match.

```
private async Task GetBlurredImageBitmapAsync(EditingSession session, byte[] blurBuffer) 
{
    WriteableBitmap wBitmap = new WriteableBitmap((int)session.Dimensions.Width, (int) session.Dimensions.Height);
    await session.RenderToWriteableBitmapAsync(wBitmap);
    session.Undo();

    blurBuffer = new byte[wBitmap.Pixels.AsBuffer().Length];
    wBitmap.Pixels.AsBuffer().CopyTo(blurBuffer);
}

private async Task getBlurredbitmap1(EditingSession session, byte[] blurBuffer) 
{
    await GetBlurredImageBitmapAsync(session, blurBuffer);
}
```

What I want is to execute this code

```
Task tsk = getBlurredbitmap1(session,blurBuffer);
tsk.ContinueWith((myTask) => 
{                    
    FACTORY.imageFusion(blurBuffer, byteStream.AsBuffer()):                       
});
```

in `myMainFunction()` after all the async methods.

Can anybody guide me as to how I can structure my code.

Comment: You seem to have already written it...is there some sort of compiler or runtime error? If so, what?

Comment: there is a System.ArgumentException after it finishes all this

Comment: Why don't you find out where that exception is coming from? It probably tells you what's wrong.

Comment: Is `myMainFunction` a constructor? If so, it should not be initiating any asynchronous work, constructors are meant to be lightweight and purely for initializing fields.